# Is it possible to incorporate one enum into another

Tags: enums, typedef, enumeration

If I have 2 enums

```
typedef enum { 
type1,
type2,
type3
} enum_one;

typedef enum {
type4,
type5,
type6
} enum_two;
```

I would like to create a composite

```
typedef enum {
enum_one,
enum_two
} another_enum;
```

Is this allowed?

Answer (score 0):

You should state your programming language, at least.

In C/C++ it is not allowed. Enums are implemented as integer constants.
You can do something like that:

```
typedef enum {
    newMember1 = enum_one.type1,
    newMember2 = enum_two.type4
} another_enum;
```

The exact syntax can be different, depending on your language and compiler.